# Proving equivalence of continuity definitions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to show that the mapping definition implies the epsilon-delta definition

---

Suppose $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in X$

Prove that:

For every open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $f(c)\in V$ There is an open set $U\subseteq X$ with $c\in U$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$

if and only if

For every $\epsilon>0,$ there is a $\delta >0:|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-c|<\delta$

---

I understand that eventually $V=(f(c)-\epsilon,f(c)+\epsilon)$ and $U=(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ but I'm having trouble throwing $x$ into it

Comment: Note that to prove the equivalency, you need to prove both implications. As for this implication, $x$ is simply a variable (not an actual point), so informally your idea is correct.

Comment: @Limsup I suppose I'm having trouble figuring out where to throw in the x and how to show that $f(U) \subseteq V$

Comment: I can figure out how to designate a $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, I just don't know how to show for "every" open V

Comment: It is well explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675843/794212. It would be a waste of time to rewrite it.

Comment: @Limsup thank you